# cannot read property of undefined while adding data to the array in angular4

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am doing the following in angular 4.I am basically have results object that derives from StressTestAnalysis interface which defines several members as listed below. The results object would contain array of objects. I need to create an object that will contain an array of data members object and single array of yaxis member as I am ignoring the existing and creating my own yaxis array which would be single.            So I am trying to push the relevant elements from the result object to the chartseries object which contains an element data number array and push it into another array that contains data element number array. The reason why I am doing this is because results contains various other members that i dont require. However i am getting a runtime error saying cannot read property series.

```
 export interface StressTestAnalysis  {

        curlevel: number;
        decrease: number;
        increase: number;
        yaxis: number[];
        data: number[];
        chartSeries: SeriesGeneric<SplineSeriesData>;
    }


 @Input() results: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];
    public chartSeries: { series: 
                      {
                        data: number[],
                      }[],
                    yAxis:number[]
                  } ;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.addSeries();

  }

 private addSeries() {
      this.results.map(r => {
  this.chartSeries.series.push( {data: r.data});

    });
```

Comment: `this.chartSeries` is an (empty) array. An array doesn't have any `series` attribute. So this attribute is undefined. So you can't call push() on it.

Comment: Sorry my bad. just updated the post

Comment: Now chartSeries itself is undefined, since you never initialize it.

Comment: And you're using `map` wrong. You should use `forEach` instead.

Comment: You have series: { data: number[] }[], which isn't going to work. Just try series: [] then the push should work. Then work from there.

Comment: I think what you are hinting is this    this.results.forEach(element => {
      if(element.data!= null)
      this.chartSeries =element.data 
   });

Comment: But how is that going to create an object chartseries that contain an object array called data

Comment: I am assigning this object to high chart and high chart expects an object that would contain parent level object that contain data object